# JAWS screen reader is reading an aria-label twice

Tags: html, jaws-screen-reader

I'm facing an issue with the JAWS reader where it is reading the  column value twice.

JAWS screen reader is reading twice `aria-label="High Priority Reminder Subject Reminder Message Attachments Present"` instead of reading single time.

```
<th id="mpage-ui-205-rowheader-211869257" headers="mpage-ui-205-Subject" class="pDkMCtVTmP2LEL-T-Lg-Gw== XSXDkcSrgRoiB3Hz9tZitg== orion-fusion-theme" scope="row" role="rowheader" style="left: 0px;">
   <div class="HcCpsY-wiG1lRx+5s2Q3cw== orion-fusion-theme" style="height: 2.5rem;">
      <div class="mpageui-Table-row-cell">
         <span class="mpageui-u-text-align mpageui-u-text-align--truncate">
            <div aria-label="High Priority Reminder . Subject Reminder Message. Attachments Present" tabindex="0" class="mpageui-u-text-align mpageui-u-text-color-attention mpageui-u-text-bold">
               <svg class="D9PJU4OMM4FofOVyof8-6w== MS7wZR3s+OQ8YdA6I9Km8Q== hY6iGjRIBoRdGFq3qcDMgQ== orion-fusion-theme mpageui-SvgIcon mpageui-SvgIcon-HighPriority mpageui-u-text-color-attention" viewBox="0 0 8 48" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="presentation" height="1em" width="1em" focusable="false">
                  <path d="M0 40h8v8H0v-8zM0 0h8v32H0V0z"></path>
               </svg>
               <span class="mpageui-u-text-align-text mpageui-u-text-color-attention mpageui-u-text-bold">Reminder Message</span>
               <svg class="D9PJU4OMM4FofOVyof8-6w== MS7wZR3s+OQ8YdA6I9Km8Q== mpageui-SvgIcon mpageui-SvgIcon-Attachment mpageui-u-text-color-secondary" viewBox="0 0 48 48" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="presentation" height="1em" width="1em" focusable="false">
                  <path d="M32 8v29a8 8 0 0 1-16 0V8a5 5 0 0 1 10 0v29a2 2 0 0 1-4 0V15h-3v22a5 5 0 0 0 10 0V8a8 8 0 0 0-16 0v29a11 11 0 0 0 22 0V8z"></path>
               </svg>
            </div>
         </span>
      </div>
   </div>
</th>
```